# Version Controlled models in Simulink Library

Tags: matlab, version-control, simulink

I have a custom simulink library which contains many models. The plan is for all individual models to be version controlled at the source.

Is it possible for me to link my library file to the blocks contained within the library so that the library automatically updates with the individual blocks.

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Your version control system is completely separate from MATLAB/Simulink. The simplest option would be to force an update to your working copy in the set-up scripts using the `system` command.